# How can I monitor bandwidth capacity over time?

Tags: wi-fi, bandwidth

I know that I can use some applications such as [Speedtest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest&hl=en) to check my current bandwidth capacity. However, I would like to monitor bandwidth capacity over time as I would like to assess the quality of the wifi connection around me throughout the day. Is there anyway to do so on Android?

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pre-destined case for apps like [OpenSignal](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.staircase3.opensignal), which are designed for mapping signals around you. [Network Signal Info](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.android.telnet) offers it as well. Both tools can be used to get a coverage map for WiFi and mobile signal, and also offer you to log signal strength.